# asio posix stream_descriptor async_read not completing on MAC

Tags: c++, linux, macos, posix, boost-asio

I am having different behavior on MAC vs Linux (ubuntu) when it comes to performing an `async_read`/`async_write` on a `asio::posix::stream_descriptor`. On my mac the iteration is performed once (outputting `iter 13`) and then hangs on the second iteration at `std::future<...>::get()` due to the `async_read(...)` and `async_write(...)` completion handles never being called. On my Linux machine, the output is as expected, i.e.

```
iter 13
iter 14
```

Interestingly, if I switch the order of the read/write then it works correctly on mac. Also, if I always read/write data that is at most `8192=(1<<13)` bytes then the read/write completion handles will be called.

The file the `stream_descriptor` is assigned to is a named pipe created by `mkfifo(...)`. Below is the minimal example I was able to make.

Does anyone know why this is hanging on a mac and if there is a fix?

```cpp
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>


int main()
{
    using stream_descriptor = boost::asio::posix::stream_descriptor;

    // setup the background thread.
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    auto worker = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_context::work>(ioc);
    std::thread thrd([&] {ioc.run(); });

    // remove and make the named pipe.
    std::string name = "/home/peter/myFifo";
    std::remove(name.c_str());
    if (mkfifo(name.c_str(), 0666))
        throw std::runtime_error("error opening fifo");

    // open the two ends of the named pipe. The 
    // std::async is there since the first will block
    // until the second is opened.
    int ifd, ofd;
    auto f = std::async([&]() {
        ifd = open(name.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    });
    ofd = open(name.c_str(), O_WRONLY);
    f.get();

    // create the asio adapter
    stream_descriptor in(ioc), out(ioc);
    in.assign(ifd);
    out.assign(ofd);

    // these lines seems to make no difference.
    //in.non_blocking(true);
    //out.non_blocking(true);

    // iterate the the messages sizes that are causing issues.
    for (int i = 13; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        int size = (1 << i);
        std::vector<char> buff(size);
        boost::asio::mutable_buffer mb(buff.data(), buff.size());
        std::promise<boost::system::error_code> p0, p1;

        boost::asio::async_read(in, mb,
            [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bt) {
                p1.set_value(ec);
            });
        boost::asio::async_write(out, mb,
            [&](const boost::system::error_code& ec, size_t bt) {
                p0.set_value(ec);
            });

        p0.get_future().get();
        p1.get_future().get();

        std::cout << "iter " << i << std::endl;
    }

    // cleanup
    worker.reset();
    thrd.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have initiated two asynchronous operation, reading and writing to/from the same memory (`mb` buffer), isn't it undefined bahaviour?, you cant write/read concurrently.

Comment: Evidently your are correct that it's UB. That said, I doubt that's the issue...

Comment: I can confirm the same issue persists if I fix the buffer issue.

Answer (score 0):

ioc.run() will exit if there are no pending operations to do,
If it exits, there will be no execution thread for async operations.

work_guard is needed to prevent ioc.run() from exiting.

[[maybe_unused]] auto work_guard = asio::make_work_guard(ioc);

ioc.run();